# WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\new\negatives/*.*'

Tags: python-2.7

when i was trying to make a text file from my negative set of images i get the above error message.My code is given below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
def create_pos_n_neg():
for pic_num in range(1,1983):
img = cv2.imread( "D:\new\negatives/"+str(pic_num)+'.jpg', 
cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
for file_type in ['D:\new\negatives']:
for img in os.listdir(file_type):
if file_type=='negatives':
line=file_type+'/'+img+'\n'
with open('bg.txt','a') as f:
f.write(line)
create_pos_n_neg()
```

Answer (score 0):

Filenames in Windows can't contain newlines. Either escape the backslashes, use a raw string, or use the other directory separator.

```
"D:\\new\\negatives/"
r"D:\new\negatives/"
"D:/new/negatives/"
```

Comment: It worked.But the text file is not created.Any idea why is that?